# How to hide keyboard and keep input focus at the same time on WKWebView in iOS17

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikit, focus, wkwebview

I am working on a rich text editor in iOS using WKWebView with a contenteditable webpage. I've implemented a custom toolbar and a collectionView that's hidden behind the keyboard.

My goal is to achieve an interaction where, upon clicking the add button on the toolbar, the keyboard retracts temporarily while the webView remains the first responder, thereby revealing the collectionView behind it.

I hope someone can help clear up my confusion. Thank you.

Currently, my approach has been to make the webView lose focus when the add button is clicked, but when the webView regains focus, the scrollView's offset within it resets to zero, which is not the behavior I desire.

[image: The image below shows what I have currently implemented.]